Can't get Play integrity API's Environment details field after enabled it in google play console
I want to check whether other apps are running that could capture the screen or control the device so I integrity 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.4.0' in my project. I followed the instruction https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup and enabled Environment details: Play Protect status && Environment details App access risk (beta) in the google play console. However, after decrypt the token, the response still doesn't have Environment details field. Here is the response I'm currently get:
{
    'tokenPayloadExternal': {
        'requestDetails': {
            'requestPackageName': 'com.microsoft.cptest.developer',
            'timestampMillis': '1723717323669',
            'requestHash': 'hashash'
        },
        'appIntegrity': {
            'appRecognitionVerdict': 'UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION',
            'packageName': 'com.microsoft.cptest.developer',
            'certificateSha256Digest': ['RyYGtfQc10IZpIFxOrqcWmYiUnI0-gmCyPwlg6V9ADc'],
            'versionCode': '205'
        },
        'deviceIntegrity': {
            'deviceRecognitionVerdict': ['MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY']
        },
        'accountDetails': {
            'appLicensingVerdict': 'UNEVALUATED'
        }
    }
}

here is the screenshot: my google play console configuration

This works after I published my test build on Google play console internal ring.
